# How to have something like head -c but working on colored characters

Tags: colors

Looks like head and sed treat color codes as actual characters. How can I get the first n actually visible characters from input?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not very  efficient, but with GNU `awk`, you could do something like:

```
gawk -v RS='\033\\[[;[:digit:]]{0,16}[[:alpha:]]|.' -v ORS= -v count=123 '
  {n += RT ~ /^[[:print:]]$/}; n > count {exit}; {print RT}'
```

(where `count` is the number of characters you want to  get).

Note that while `head -c` counts in number of *bytes*, the above counts in number of *characters*.

We're only considering control characters like newline, carriage return or tab, and escape sequences that are in the format: `\e[123;123x` like the colour ones (where `x` is `m`) or cursor positioning ones (where `x` is `H`).

Comment: I'm looking for something very fast. Is there maybe a language in which I could easily write and compile this?